# Cannot put CSV file into database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I have written the following PHP code to load a CSV file into database. But the query isn't executing.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost'; 
$dbuser = 'root'; 
$dbpass = ''; 
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(mysqli_select_db($conn,"test"))
{
    printf("Success");
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'output.csv' INTO TABLE new COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '\"\' ESCAPED BY '\"\' " ;
printf($query);

if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
printf("query executed");
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Please tell me what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what the error is. If you don't get one it's probably because you haven't turned on error reporting, so fix that first. Does this query run properly outside of PHP?

Comment: Where file output.csv is located? On server or client host?

Comment: @tadman When i run the query on mysql it runs properly.

Comment: @Max P. the output.csv file is present in test folder of mysql in xampp

Comment: Maybe your connection is failing, but since you don't check for errors you're telling PHP you really don't care, it's just doing as it's told. You can fix that by turning on exceptions.

Comment: May be path to file is incorrect, try to specify full path.

Comment: @tadman the connection isnt failing i added the exception for it and it doesn't return error.

Comment: Either the connection failed, the query failed, or the file is empty if nothing happened. Try putting in some success code, like return the number of rows inserted from your query result. Right now even if this did work you wouldn't see any useful output.

Comment: @tadman the query isn't executing.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this comes from a mangled conversion from regular text to PHP string:

```
ENCLOSED BY '\"\' ESCAPED BY '\"\'
```

This should probably be:

```
ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"'
```

The query itself is invalid. You *should* be getting an error back.